# How to copy all the files inside the directory to another folder inside the directory with terminal?

Tags: command-line, bash, directory

I copy the files inside a folder to another folder inside the directory like this :

```
cp -a folderone/ foldertwo
```

Now how can I copy all the files in the directory to foldertwo in the directory ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use either relative or absolute paths on your target folder (assuming you are currently at the origin folder).

For calling folders names relative to your current path you use ../ to go up one level.

Absolute paths are a sure shot. Type / on the target folder and press tab (autocomplete is your friend) and keep autocompleting till you create the full path for your folder.

Most likely, you will be working with files on your home. You can use `~/` to reference the root of your home folder. So do `~/` and use tab to autocomplete your path (you can do it for source and target folder, if you don't want to cd to either of those folders)

Comment: ```cp -a ../name/ dest``` I ran this and it worked but it goes into a loop and copies the files to the dest folder over and overagain so If I go to dest folder there is another dest folder inside it and it goes on and on . How can I copy files once only ?

Comment: `cp -T source dest`

Comment: @bac0n It throws an error : ```illegal option -- T
usage: cp [-R [-H | -L | -P]] [-fi | -n] [-apvXc] source_file target_file
       cp [-R [-H | -L | -P]] [-fi | -n] [-apvXc] source_file ... target_directory
```

Comment: then this does not sound like ubuntu, macos?

Comment: Also `cp /name/* dest/` works. That's what I generally use.